# No memory leaks or errors but my code slows down exponentially C#

Tags: c#

I am perplexed by this issue. I believe I'm just missing an easy problem right in front of my face but I'm at the point where I need a second opinion to point out anything obvious that I'm missing. I minimized my code and simplified it so it only shows a small part of what it does. The full code is just many different calculations added on to what I have below.

```
for (int h = 2; h < 200; h++)
{
     var List1 = CalculateSomething(testValues, h);
     var masterLists = await AddToRsquaredList("Calculation1", h, actualValuesList, List1, masterLists.Item1, masterLists.Item2);

     var List2 = CalculateSomething(testValues, h);
     masterLists = await AddToRsquaredList("Calculation2", h, actualValuesList, List2, masterLists.Item1, masterLists.Item2);

     var List3 = CalculateSomething(testValues, h);
     masterLists = await AddToRsquaredList("Calculation3", h, actualValues, List3, masterLists.Item1, masterLists.Item2);
}

public static async Task<(List<RSquaredValues3>, List<ValueClass>)> AddToRsquaredList(string valueName, int days, 
        IEnumerable<double> estimatedValuesList, IEnumerable<double> actualValuesList, 
        List<RSquaredValues3> rSquaredList, List<ValueClass> valueClassList)
    {
        try
        {
            RSquaredValues3 rSquaredValue = new RSquaredValues3
            {
                ValueName = valueName,
                Days = days,
                RSquared = GoodnessOfFit.CoefficientOfDetermination(estimatedValuesList, actualValuesList),
                StdError = GoodnessOfFit.PopulationStandardError(estimatedValuesList, actualValuesList)
            };

            int comboSize = 15;
            double max = 0;
            var query = await rSquaredList.OrderBy(i => i.StdError - i.RSquared).DistinctBy(i => i.ValueName).Take(comboSize).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (query.Count > 0)
            {
                max = query.Last().StdError - query.Last().RSquared;
            }
            else
            {
                max = 10000000;
            }

            if ((rSquaredValue.StdError - rSquaredValue.RSquared < max || query.Count < comboSize) && rSquaredList.Contains(rSquaredValue) == false)
            {
                rSquaredList.Add(rSquaredValue);
                valueClassList.Add(new ValueClass { ValueName = rSquaredValue.ValueName, ValueList = estimatedValuesList, Days = days });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ThrowExceptionInfo(ex);
        }

        return (rSquaredList, valueClassList);
    }
```

Comment: I would say, the problem lies in big data collection and use if Linq. Linq is nice and fine, when you do not need speed and prefer simple way how to write code. But unfortunately it is not a good idea, when you need to process a big amount of data, or speed. I would recommend doing the processing in a standard way and optimise processed data count. See your code. First you sort the whole list (`Orderby`), the you use `DistinctBy`, use `Take` and then process only a single value. It is really necessary to process all the data for a single (`Last`) value? Can not be this process optimised?

Comment: I disagree with the Linq comment. The issue is not Linq itself, it's the specific use of Linq and the implementation of the underlying collection. When used correctly it's a fantastic tool and is very performant. I do agree the code here needs some rethinking though...

Comment: You do multiple iterations over growing collections, not unexpected that the performance deteriorates as the collections grow. What are `GoodnessOfFit.CoefficientOfDetermination` and `GoodnessOfFit.PopulationStandardError` doing? Additional iterations I presume?

Comment: You should performance profile each function call and get a breakdown of how much time each takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is clearly a significance to `StdError - RSquared`, so change `RSquaredValues3` to expose that value (i.e. calculate it once, on construction, since the values do not change) rather than recalculating it in multiple places during the processing loop.

The value in this new property is the way that the list is being sorted. Rather than sorting the list over and over again, consider keeping the items in the list in that order in the first place. You can do this by ensuring that each time an item gets added, it is inserted in the right place in the list. This is called an [insertion sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). (I have assumed that [`SortedList<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) is inappropriate due to duplicate 'key's.)

Similar improvements can be made to avoid the need for `DistinctBy(i => i.ValueName)`. If you are only interested in distinct value names, then consider avoiding inserting the item if it is not providing an improvement.

Your `List` needs to grow during your processing - under the hood, the list doubles every time it grows, so the number of growths is O(log(n)). You can specify a suggested capacity in construction. If you specify the expected size large enough at the start, then the list will not need to do this during your processing.

The `await` of the `ToListAsync` is not adding any advantage to this code, as far as I can see.

The check for `rSquaredList.Contains(rSquaredValue) == false` looks like a redundant check, since this is a reference comparison of a newly instantiated item which cannot have been inserted in the list. So you can remove it to make it run faster.

Comment: I need to clarify a few things from my code. The RSquaredValues3 class is an auto generated class using EF6 and also I perhaps simplified my code too much but what I'm doing in the loop is doing many separate calculations inside the loop and then the next method calculates the rsquared values and adds it to my rsquared table

Answer (score 0):

With all that use of `Task` and `await`, you are not actually gaining anything at the moment, since you have a single thread handling it and are waiting for execution sequentially, so it appears to all be overhead. I am not sure if you can parallelize this workload but the main loop from 2 to 200 seems like a prime candidate for a `Parallel.For()` loop instead. You should also look into using a `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag()` for your master list if you implement parallelism to avoid deadlock issues.

Comment: `you are returning value tuples containing presumably large data sets`
It's value tuple containing two references. I doubt it has any impact on performance.

Comment: I am very skeptical about the claim that using value tuples would cause an issue. If anything the collections are more of a problem. List is a convenient class but it has to reallocate every time it grows. If you are worried about excessive allocation and copying this is what you should blame.

Comment: Hmm nevermind, it seems I need to retract this part of the answer, I have misread something somewhere.